# AngularJS Fail to pass new value from textbox for update data in sql

Tags: angularjs, input

I'm trying to pass my new data to update data in my database but the input still sending the old value from it first query. I mean I already type new information in my textbox but it still send own value. Post data is fine and php part is fine, but I need new value that I have typed to be sent not old value. Please help !

Here are my codes:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in content | filter:usercontent" >
  <input type="text" value="{{x.Username}}"> </br> </br> 
  <input type="text"  value="{{x.Firstname}}">  </br> </br> 
   <input type="text" value="{{x.Lastname}}"> </br> </br> 
  <input type="text" value="{{x.Email}}">  </br> </br> 
   <input type="text" value="{{x.Tel}}"> </br> </br> 
  <td><button ng-click="edituser(x.Username,x.Firstname,x.Lastname,x.Email,x.Tel)" >Edit</button></td>
  <!--<td><button ng-click="deleteData(x.Username)">Del</button></td>-->
  </br> </br> 
</div>
</div></center>


$scope.edituser = function(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Tel)
{
//console.log($scope.usercontent);
    var postdata = {

        'Username' : Username,
        'Firstname' : Firstname,
        'Lastname' : Lastname,
        'Email' : Email,
        'Tel' : Tel

    };
    var path = 'http://localhost/edituser.php';
    console.log(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Tel);
    console.log(getCookie("Username"));
                    $http.post(path, postdata
                ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                        console.log("pass data complete !");

                }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs

                  alert("NO");
                }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that you should define ng-model for all text boxes :

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in content | filter:usercontent" >
  <input type="text" ng-model="x.Username" value="{{x.Username}}"> </br> </br> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="x.Firstname"  value="{{x.Firstname}}">  </br> </br> 
   <input type="text" ng-model="x.Lastname" value="{{x.Lastname}}"> </br> </br> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="x.Email" value="{{x.Email}}">  </br> </br> 
   <input type="text" ng-model="x.Tel" value="{{x.Tel}}"> </br> </br> 
  <td><button ng-click="edituser(x)" >Edit</button></td>
  <!--<td><button ng-click="deleteData(x.Username)">Del</button></td>-->
  </br> </br> 
</div>
</div></center>
```

In your controller  :

```
 $scope.edituser = function(x)
    {
     // variable x will contain all value of that textboxes which will be updated if user has changed it from textboxes
```

Answer (score 1):

You send only the predefined values, that you set in the controller. You should bind your inputs to some model.Try to use the **ng-model** directive. Try to read and understand the [ng-model documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

```
  <input ng-model="postdata.username" name="username" class="my-input" />
```

then in your controller you can change/do something with the value

```
$scope.postdata.username = "";
```